# Drive Api Java : MediaContent & MediaSource alternative for Drive Api

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, gmail

Using Drive api., I want to send a file as an attachment("DON'T WANT TO SAVE IT TO DRIVE").

Earlier I was using 'Document List Api' to do the same using these classes

```
com.google.gdata.data.MediaContent 
com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaSource
```

Now, I want to achieve the same using Drive Api Classes. So what are the alternatives for these classes in Drive Api.

Comment: @ pinoyyid : I mean to Mail a file as attachment.

Comment: Hmm, why not use the gmail api to send emails ? 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending